# How to scroll the underlying MatDialog when MatSelect is open?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

When opening a `MatSelect` in a regular page, it is possible to customize the scroll behavior through the `MAT_SELECT_SCROLL_STRATEGY` injection token and use the `NoopScrollStrategy` in order to scroll the underlying page while keeping the `MatSelect` in place.

However, when the `MatSelect` is being opened from a `MatDialog`, the `MAT_SELECT_SCROLL_STRATEGY` has no effect at all and I can't scroll the underlying `MatDialog`.

I've created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4rhr8z) to demonstrate the problem.

One workaround is to set a `backDropClass` with `pointer-events: none` but it also disables the close behavior when I click it, which I want to keep. I'd also like to avoid hacks based on `z-index` if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to close the matSelect when clicked outside menu using pure css but wasn't able to find a way. So I had to make code changes in the ts file.

I have edited you [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d9gt5v?file=src/app/app.component.ts) here and it seems to be working. Please verify..

Adding the below code in your global style.css/scss file will allow you to scroll the dialog while the matselect is open and will also enable the dialog to close when clicked outside:

```
.cdk-overlay-backdrop.cdk-overlay-backdrop-showing {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.cdk-overlay-dark-backdrop {
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}
```

To close the matSelect when clicked outside menu, had to make .ts code changes. Please refer the stackblitz link for that..

Comment: As I said it disables the close behavior when I click outside the menu

Comment: Okay... I thought you meant to close the dialog when clicked outside the dialog instead of the menu.. I will make the changes.

Comment: Made the changes to close the menu when clicked outside. I have updated my answer. Please verify..

Comment: Yes it works although very hacky, I'd have to copy/paste the `@HostListener` wherever I have a similar case. My question was more about an integrated solution (at least reusable)

Comment: Thanks for your research effort, I'd be interested in a solution that wouldn't require to add custom code to future developments that require the same behavior

Comment: I have observed that mat-autocomplete behaves in the way you wanted..like scroll enabled when menu is open and menu close when clicked outside. But I wasn't able to figure out how. Maybe this can help you in solving the issue..

Comment: Really? Interesting will have a look. If you find a solution based on this, feel free to share it, all I want is to award that bounty!